# How Do I Access S3 Bucket Files in Browser Using AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser

I have accessKeyId and secretAccessKey for AWS S3 bucket. How do I access the video files on the bucket using the browser?

I'm using React and Node(Nest.js). I would like to play the video files on the React Frontend

Comment: Is the user of your web page supplying the access key and secret key to the page when they visit it? Hopefully you are not planning to store these credentials visibly within the webpage. Assuming you have AWS credentials, you can use the AWS JavaScript SDK in the browser to create a pre-signed URL for the video file in S3, then provide that URL to your video player.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to generate a presigned url now using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.html. Do you know what the clientParams 
 and getObjectParams are?

Comment: See [Interface S3ClientConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/s3clientconfig.html) for clientParams and [Interface GetObjectCommandInput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/interfaces/getobjectcommandinput.html) for getObjectParams. Probably simpler initially to search for SDK v3 code examples that creates an S3 Client and uses GetObjectCommand.

Comment: Got it working, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your web page has AWS credentials, then you can use the AWS JavaScript SDK in the browser to [create a pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.html) for the video file in S3, then provide that URL to your video player.

If the web page doesn't have AWS credentials and can't easily get them, then consider using AWS Amplify or write a small server-side component to do this on behalf of your client.

Note that pre-signed URLs have an associated expiration date/time.